# clojure subvec O(n) instead of O(1)?

Tags: clojure

So I have

```
(def a (vec (range 1000000)))
(def b (vec (range 100000)))
```

and to take the rest of both vector

```
(time (dorun (subvec b 1 100000)))
=>"Elapsed time: 3.585556 msecs"
(time (dorun (subvec a 1 1000000)))
=>"Elapsed time: 43.088316 msecs"
```

The doc says this operation takes O(1). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That time is being used by `dorun` to traverse the entire vector slice.

Vectors are not lazy, by the way; wrapping them in `dorun` / `doall` is pointless.

Comment: i see.. So I can just do something like `(do (subvec b 1) nil)` to test it's performance?

Comment: You really should use a proper benchmarking library; [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) is the standard Clojure solution. (`(require '[criterium.core :as c])`, then `(c/bench (subvec b 1))`.) Getting benchmarking right in the presence of a JIT compiler is quite challenging.

Comment: Try replacing `dorun` with `count` (or `first` ... anything O(1)), and you'll see no significant difference in the times.